# Can I have an os on a usb that can be used ran as a vm and as a physical machine?

Tags: usb, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

I want to be able to have a linux distro stored on a usb which I can run on both my windows and mac computers as a vm and also possibly being able to physically boot the vm on my mac as running 2 opperating systems at once drains the battery fast. I have seen people say that vm images are compatible cross platform, and that it is possible to convert a vm image to a physical machine, but is it possible for this to be done without converting the image? I know with parallels you can run an image as ether a vm or as a dual boot but I dont know if it is possible to run this image on both windows and mac

I am doing comsci at uni and I have a windows desktop which I prefer to use at home and a mac laptop I use at uni and I want to be able to have a linux os with persistant files which can be run on both. I would prefer that I can run it as a physical partition on my mac but it must at least be able to be run as a virtual machine on both.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  What you are asking for is exactly what a Linux Live USB is.  You can install Linux to a USB drive, configure it however you want, and boot from it.  You can also boot that USB device from inside a VM and interact with it.

Comment: I'd add that there's a specific feature required for this called USB passthrough

Comment: Theree is no need for USB passthrough.  No devices are being passed.

Comment: you either need a passthrough, or you need a VM Virtual Hard Disk in order for the VM to access the USB contents. In the later case, a physical computer won't be able to boot from it

Comment: @tuskiomi At least in VirtualBox you can make use of the whole physical drive of an USB stick and "mount" it as a virtual drive so that you can run it in VirtualBox. I did this once under Windows, therefore it is possible to use a regular USB stick directly.

Comment: @Robert I think that's just USB passthrough but they didn't tell you the name

Comment: @tuskiomi I am very sure that it wasn't USB passthrough. The VirtualBox disk file was accessing the USB stick as RAW device via PhysicalDrive (Windows block device access). It was like this tutorial: https://www.serverwatch.com/guides/using-a-physical-hard-drive-with-a-virtualbox-vm/

Comment: @Robert that sounds like USB passthrough with extra steps